# Express JS Passing variable to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, view, render

In my Express JS app, I am using **ejs view engine**, I want to pass variable to javascript file on client side.

This is my render:

```
return res.render('data/show', {
    data: data
});
```

This is working for me:

```
<script>
    var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

But my function is in separate .js file that I am including, when I am using the same code:

```
function gettingData() {
    var data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
    console.log(data);
}
```

I am getting syntax error:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with EJS, but my guess would be that:

```
<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>
```

...only works as a substitution in the HTML files being served up by the node server (with an .ejs extension, I believe), but that the above would come straight through as-is in a separate .js file being loaded separately.

Comment: <%- JSON.stringify(data) %> works only in .html file. I am looking for way to access this 'data' in .js file that is included.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a shot...`JSON.stringify(<%= data %>)`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: unfortunately your code is giving me the same syntax error. It seems that <%%> ejs marks are not recognized inside .js file.

Comment: Put the whole thing in quotes. `var someVar = "<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>"`

Comment: I was trying this also. Result is that someVar is type of String and equal "<%= JSON.stringify(data) %>". This was't even executed, javascript is treating it's as regular string.

Comment: It worked for me...but just realized that it was because I was using it within the script tags in the .ejs file.

Comment: Yes, exactly, with <script> tag everything is workin fine, but my script is getting big, that's why it's necessary to include another file and not write everything inside .html.

Comment: Another way to go about this could be...put your JS code in between script tags and put them in a EJS file...then include it in your main EJS file using `<%- include('external_file') %>`.

Comment: It can be also solution, right now what I decided to create <div> tag that will contains necessary data (because they are only two numbers) and then inside javascript simply get value.